# QT- Signal and Slot setEnabled(bool) slot not working

Tags: c++, qt

I have been working on a simple notepad application using `QT`, and am currently stuck at a place where I have to disable the `actionUndo` and `actionRedo` when undo or redo are not applicable respectively. I used the connect method of `QT`, and currently my `constructor function` (along with `includes`) looks like this:

```
#include "notepad.h"
#include "ui_notepad.h"
#include "about.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontDialog>
#include <QTextCursor>

Notepad::Notepad(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Notepad)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("QNotepad");
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/icons/icons/qnotepad.png"));
    setCentralWidget(ui->textBody);

    //Enabling the options, only when applicable
    connect(ui->textBody, SIGNAL(undoAvailable(bool)), ui->actionUndo, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
    connect(ui->textBody, SIGNAL(redoAvailable(bool)), ui->actionRedo, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));

}
```

Full sources are [here](https://github.com/lzzy12/Qnotepad)

But seems it is not working as when I run the program, the `actionUndo` and `actionRedo` remains enabled even when there is no undo and redo operations available.

[image: A screenshot of the problem]

I am using Arch Linux as the primary development environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Ui elements (widgets, actions, etc.) are enabled by default, so you need  to uncheck the enabled flag for the Undo and Redo action in the property window of Qt designer for your notepad.ui file. 
Alternatively you could do it in the constructor of your window like this:

```
ui->actionUndo->setEnabled(false);
ui->actionRedo->setEnabled(false);

//Enabling the options, only when applicable
connect(ui->textBody, &QTextEdit::undoAvailable, ui->actionUndo, &QAction::setEnabled);
connect(ui->textBody, &QTextEdit::undoAvailable, ui->actionRedo, &QAction::setEnabled);
```

In this way they will be on/off only when the QTextEdit emits the signal.

Also consider to use the functor syntax for your signal/slot connection, as shown in my code snipped, because it has several advantages. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html) to learn more.